# Sqlplus format 3 place number, i.e. 150 to 1.50 for spool output

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a query in sqlplus that returns data to a csv file. One piece of data is an amount. It is displayed, for example, as `150`. I need it to display `1.50`. When I try using `$9.99` or just `9.99` to try to format it, I get `######` in place of the amount.

I am new to sqlplus scripts and I need help. All other aspects of the query are working as expected. I have tried multiple masks but they just give me results such as `150.00` or `1500.00`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the number into cents e.g. / 100 and to_char if you want the output to also include $'s

```
select to_char(150/100, '$9,999.99') from dual;
$1.50
select to_char(999999/100, '$9,999.99') from dual;
$9,999.99
```

note:
you will need to specify with enough precision:

```
select to_char(99999999/100, '$9,999.99') from dual;
##########

select to_char(99999999/100, '$999,999.99') from dual;
$999,999.99
```